# Should I mop or sanitize subfloor prior to flooring install?

Tags: cleaning, subfloor

During the past few months of renovation I tore up a bunch of laminate flooring to address various issues and I am finally circling back to installing the new floating floor. I'm realizing after doing a thorough vacuuming with the shop vac that there is still a lot of dirt and dust on the osb/plywood(mixed around the house). I'll be laying underlayment down (Quietwalk) but want to make sure I'm not trapping a lot of organic matter(dirt, drywall dust, sawdust etc) that may lead to mold etc. if there was ever moisture trapped.

Wondering if I should mop and let it dry? Apply TSP or concrobium or bleach? Or seal it all in with primer just to be sure(BIN 123 or something)

Or am I just overthinking this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not mop, and you should not worry about it. *The entirety of your subfloor is organic.* Mopping will only create an actual problem--moisture soaked into your subfloor.

If you saw what carpet and other flooring typically goes over after a new build or remodel you'd realize that your concerns are unfounded. Vacuum well to prevent dust creep later and carry on.